# File system unmounted after reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, filesystem

I will try to describe my problem as clear as possible. Recently i installed Ubuntu 16.04 on regular PC (via bootable USB). Then few days later after several sleep/wake cycles it appeared that there are some memory errors (more specifically intellij IDE went crazy when switching between tabs). Given the following i rebooted the system. After that i was welcomed by the grub console. I tried the following:

```
grub> boot
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

So i started to worry. Then after some digging i learned i can list files present on the machine, so i did it

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)
```

But then it turns out that i cannot see anything there:

```
grub> ls (hd0,1)
(hd0, 1): Filesystem is fat
```

I was following this article: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux

I could reinstall system, but installer does not detect any existing disk partitions (so i would lose my data, and ofcourse i have some uncommited changes, because life can't be to easy it appears).

Comment: I would forget trying to fix your fs/Ubuntu system for now, and check out your hardware. Boot your install media (or any 'live' system) and check your HDD/sdd's health status & ram-- ie. check your hardware.  You could run a ramtest (memtest86+) via install-usb-media.  Use `smartctl` to check hdd/sdd (you need to add `smartmontools`) from install media.  If all is ok, then you can being restoration of system... My 2c

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue, using the following steps:

1. Run ubuntu from live usb
2. Install testdisk command (need to enable universe repostiory, easy to google so let's skip it)
3. testdisk is very intuitive, i simply followed the instructions and recovered my partitions. And my system boots just fine.

   Important mention: i did run smartctl before this process, it did not find any potential disk failures